# Showing $a_0 + a_1 n + \ldots + a_{k-1} n^{k-1} + a_k n^k = \Theta(n^k)$ when $a_k > 0$

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics, computer-science

As exercise I am trying to show

$$
f(n) = a_0 + a_1 n + \ldots + a_{k-1} n^{k-1} + a_k n^k = \Theta(n^k)
$$
when $a_k > 0$.

My proof is based on the idea of showing $f(n) = O(n^k)$ and $f(n) = \Omega(f(n))$.

**Proof $f(n) = O(n^k)$**

This is trivial since

$$f(n) \leq |f(n) | \leq |a_0 | + \ldots + | a_k| n^k$$

So if $c = |a_0| + \ldots + |a_k|$ and $n_0 \geq 1$ the definition of $O$ is met.

**Proof $f(n) = \Omega(n^k)$**

A bit trickier and I don't know I can make it simpler...
Let's define
$$
\hat{a} = \min_{0\leq j \leq k - 1}{a_j}
$$

If $\hat{a} \geq 0$ then for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have $f(n) \geq a_{k} n^k$. If $\hat{a} < 0$ we have

$$
f(n) = a_0 + a_1 n + \ldots + a_{k-1} n^{k-1} + a_k n^k \geq k \hat{a} n^{k-1} + a_k n^k
$$

Hence if I showed there're $c$ and $n_0$ such that for all $n\geq n_0$

$$
k \hat{a} n^{k-1} + a_k n^k \geq cn^k
$$
I am done. I observe

$$
k \hat{a} n^{k-1} + a_k n^k \geq cn^k \iff \frac{k \hat{a}}{n} + a_k \geq c \iff \frac{k \hat{a}}{n} \geq c - a_{k}
$$
I can pick $c > a_k$ so $c - a_k > 0$ which leads me to have
$$
n \geq \frac{k \hat{a}}{a_k - c}
$$
which has solution for natural $n$

Overall if I fix $c > a_k$ and $n_0 \geq \max\left\{1, \frac{k\hat{a}}{a_k - c}\right\}$  I have

$$
f(n) \geq c n ^k
$$

Combining $f(n) = O(n^k)$ and $f(n) = \Omega(n^k)$ I have $f(n) = \Theta(n^k)$

Is this proof correct?

Comment: You can also say that $n^{-k}f(n)\to a_k>0$ as $n\to +\infty$. So for all sufficiently large $n$, $\frac{a_k}{2} <n^{-k}f(n)<\frac{3a_k}{2}$.

Comment: I could, however I didn't want to rely on analytic tools.